# How to initialize java Condition in Hazelcast

Tags: java, spring, conditional-statements, locking, hazelcast

I'm new to Hazelcast and I'm trying to create java Condition in Hazelcast but I have no idea how to do so.
Is it possible? if so, anyone know how to do that?

```
@Getter
@Service
public class HazelcastService {

    private FencedLock lock;
    private PNCounter counter;
    private Condition notEmpty;
    private IList<PushStatementObjectRequestDTO> listData;

    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        lock = hazelcastInstance.getCPSubsystem().getLock(LIST_LOCK);
        counter = hazelcastInstance.getPNCounter(COUNTER);
        notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
        listData = hazelcastInstance.getList(LIST_DATA);
    }
}
```

I found ICondition interface, but im not sure how to use it

Comment: Which Hazelcast version are you using?

Comment: I'm using <dependency>
   <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
   <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: In the 4.x and 5.x series there is no Condition implementation. It was available in 3.x series, but it was deprecated when Hazelcast introduced the CP Subsystem. Note that, the implementation in 3.x had some problems so I wouldn't advise using it. It is better to stick to the latest version even if it has no Condition. See this analysis for the problems of the concurrency primitives in 3.x series https://jepsen.io/analyses/hazelcast-3-8-3
See this blog post for the CP subsystem https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-imdg-3-12-introduces-cp-subsystem/

Answer (score 0):

I find the Java API documentation very clear about how to use  `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` interface. It also provides a very good example of how to block writing items into a buffer when the buffer is full or block taking items from it while the buffer is empty.

Please have a look at this:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

In Hazelcast the only difference is that you have a distributed condition `com.hazelcast.core.ICondition` implementing the  `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition`.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:**

From Hazelcast IMDG 4.0 or later you can instantiate a `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` on a distributed lock using code similar with below:

```
public void howToGetCondition() {
    var hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    var cpSubsystem = hazelcastInstance.getCPSubsystem();
    
    var bufferLock = cpSubsystem.getLock("buffer-lock");
    var condition = bufferLock.newCondition();
    // Do stuff with your condition
}
```

Of course it can no longer be an `com.hazelcast.core.ICondition` which was removed in 4.0

Hope this helped too

Comment: Yes, you are right but I'm not able to find the Hazelcast interface you mentioned

Comment: OK so I guess you are trying to use a 4.x Hazelcast IMDG version. If you go here https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/migrate/upgrading-from-imdg-3 you can read somewhere the following: "In IMDG 4.0 and afterwards, these deprecated implementations and additionally ILock and ICondition interfaces are completely removed."

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer about how to get hold by a `Condition`. Please note that that is not an ICondition which is gone.